# How do you trigger the onMtuChanged method via a connection event?

Tags: android, bluetooth

The [Android Bluetooth documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onMtuChanged(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)) states the following for the onMtuChanged callback:

> Callback indicating the MTU for a given device connection has changed.
> This callback is triggered in response to the BluetoothGatt#requestMtu
> function, or in response to a connection event.

I am able to trigger onMtuChanged when I call the [requestMtu method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#requestMtu(int)), but I noticed that the documentation states that the onMtuChanged method can also be triggered by a connection event. What does the documentation mean by "connection event" (connect?, disconnect?)? How do you trigger onMtuChanged via a connection event?